# How can I calculate the distance between two positions in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

Can anyone help me with that. at mysql database I have **providers** table which contains **longitude** and **latitude** attributes, there is a user who will looking for providers who will be after **x km** from him so suppose that I have the user **longitude** and **latitude**. Is there any way to do that with mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It requires MySQL’s built-in Math functions, including  cos(), sin(), acos() and radians().

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(latitude) ) *
              cos( radians( latitude) ) 
        * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(longitude ) )
        + sin( radians(latitude) ) * sin(radians(latitude)) ) 
    ) AS distance 
    FROM myTable
```

Where value 3959 is the Earth radius in miles